# Согласование числительных

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно согласовать числительное в предложении: *Средний срок лечения составил (26 ± 1) дней/день*?

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен с заключением в скобки числа 26 и не понимаю, о каких плюсах и минусах идёт речь при состоявшемся лечении. При наличии ± указание на усреднённость также излишне.

Если запись подправить, задачка ваша решится без помех: *срок лечения составит 26 (±1) день*. Возможно и улучшение рокировкой: *срок лечения составит (±1) 26 дней*. (Единица измерения склоняется по последнему числительному.)

Comment: Это научный текст, так там обозначаются средние значения. Например: "Теоретический простой фабрики составил 50 ± 2 дней /дня. Почему в скобках? Вот здесь вопрос у самой. У Мильчина написано, Числовое значение с допуском или с предельными отклонениями при сочетании с обозначением единицы физ. величины требуется заключить в скобки либо обозначение единицы поставить и после числового значения, и после допуска или предельного отклонения. Правильно: (10 ± 0,1) мм; 10 мм ± 0,1 мм. Неправильно:    
10 ± 0,1 мм. Не знаю, распространяется ли это на %, людей, дни и т.д., например: (89 ± 1) %.

Comment: Все единицы измерения в математических выражениях имеют несклоняемую универсальную краткую запись. Тогда о чём вопрос?

Comment: Я попыталась объяснить о "каких плюсах и минусах идет речь". На вопрос Вы дали ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Если текст настолько научный, что происходит путаница со словом день, надо переходить на измерение в сутках и его краткую запись.

Comment: Там не только со словом день, очень много таких записей, в которых согласуется то первое числительное, то второе. Поэтому и возник вопрос.

Comment: Нет такой единицы измерения в математике — день.

Comment: Это понятно, вдруг по аналогии? (Мильчин же не мог всего учесть.)